# Ruby - Best way to check args in a new call when overriding a class?

Tags: ruby

I have a class called `Polynomial`that is overriding `Array`.  I need to check that the `array` being passed to it on `Polynomial.new([])` has at least 2 args.

I was thinking something like the following, but it's causing weird behavior in my tests.

```
class Polynomial < Array

    def initialize(coefficients)
        if coefficients.size < 2
            puts "you need to have more than 1 arg"
        else
            self = coefficients
        end
    end
```

Comment: `self = coefficients`???

Comment: And if coefficents isn't an array, but does have a size method. Potential for weird is extreme...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *insist* on keeping `Polynomial` an `Array` (I agree with @matt that this is probably a *bad* idea) then you still *should* call `#super` in your `initialize`, at least if all is well. Given you would like to be given an array as the argument list you might resort to a [splat argument](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html) which will *always* turn out to be an array. But since you asked I will include the check in my example code:

```
class Polynomial < Array

    def initialize(*coeffs)
        if coeffs.is_a? Array
            coefficients=coeffs.flatten
            if (coefficients.size < 2)
                puts "you need to have more than 1 arg"
            else 
              super(coefficients)
            end
        else
            puts "you need to give me an array"
        end
    end

end
```

This checks if your argument is an array (which it always will be because of the splat). Ruby methods tend to be generous about the "things" you can throw at them, so this methods calls `#flatten` on your args list in order to allow both versions:

```
p1=Polynomial.new([1,2])
=> [1, 2]
p2=Polynomial.new(1,2)
=> [1, 2]
```

It checks your condition of at least 2 elements, but you would probably like to add additional conditions such as all of your arguments should be numerical (as it is you can have any `Object` in your `coeffs`, but you probably only want `Numeric`, another reason not to subclass `Array`). You may add more conditions as you see fit.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation.  Would it be better to make the coefficient array an instance variable and set it in initialize?

Comment: @JoeEssey: I would almost definitely consider that to be the better option, as your `Polynomial` will basically not want to do *anything* an `Array` usually does. You probably want it to `compute(x)` in order to get some `y`, but you do not want to `poly[1..2]` as an `Array` would. But of course in the end it depends on your application. If you *require* your `Polynomial` to do everything an `Array` does you should subclass, otherwise you should use an instance variable and provide a convenient set of methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is how a method can know how many arguments it received when called:

```
def meth(*args)
  puts args.length
end
```

So you might like to design Polynomial to receive a variable number of arguments in its initializer, instead of an array of arguments, and then use `*args` to set the contents of the array. (I am not convinced, by the way, that Polynomial should *be* an array; one rather expects it to *have* an array...)